# Significance of "-m" option in svn import

Tags: svn, import

What does the "-m" option specify in svn import command? For eg:-
"svn import project file:///repository_name/project -m "First Import" "

Answer (score 2):

From the command line output of `svn help import`:

```
  -m [--message] ARG       : specify log message ARG
```

For a better understanding of log messages, see `svn help log`.

Answer (score 1):

As Chad suggested, `--message` option is used to specify a commit log message.

Unless you have [an external editor](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/externaleditors/), you'll get the error when attempting to commit or import without specifying `-m` option:

```
svn: E205007: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found
```